# how to split a column into multiple value using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have thousands of rows with data and I would like to find out if the column called "Last 
Name "  contains both First Name and Last Name (could be middle initial too).  What SQL command 
do I use ?  (SQL Server 2008).  Once I find it, how do I split the Last Name field and place 
first name or middle initial in their own columns ?

For example:

```
First Name        MI       Last Name

John              B.       Smith  
                           Karen A. Jones
Jane                       Lawrence
                           Joan K. Bates
```

Could it be done in Excel as well ?

Comment: Lots of variables - Does it always contain a middle name?  What about last names with spaces? ("Van der Waal")

Comment: last name has spaces, but sometimes may not have

Comment: I agree with D Stanley, this kind of problem requires some artificial intelligence and it's not solvable in general. Unless you do a lot of assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look for spaces in the last name:

```
select *
from t
where lastname like '% %';
```

You could look for rows where the first name is missing:

```
select *
from t
where firstname is null or firstname = '';
```

EDIT:

If we assume that the names are "simple" as given in the sample data, you can do:

```
update t
    set firstname = left(lastname, charindex(' ', lastname) - 1),
        lastname = right(lastname, charindex(' ', reverse(lastname))),
        mi = (case when lastname like '% % %'
                   then rtrim(ltrim(substring(lastname, charindex(' ', lastname + 1), 2)))
              end)
    where lastname like '% %' and firstname is null;
```

This makes lots of assumptions about the formats . . . that there are no complete middle names, that there are no honorics, that there are no suffixes, that there are no multiple spaces together.  But if your data is simple, it should work.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14413) is an example of the logic in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff.  Once I find those rows, how do I split the Last Name field and place first name in its own column ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in two passes:

```
-- Set first name
UPDATE names
SET FirstName = SUBSTR(LastName,1,CHARINDEX(' ',LastName) - 1),
    LastName = SUBSTR(LastName,CHARINDEX(' ',LastName) + 1, LEN(LastName))
WHERE FirstNAme IS NULL
    AND CHARINDEX(' ',LastName) > 0

-- Set middle name
UPDATE names
SET MI = SUBSTR(LastName,1,CHARINDEX(' ',LastName) - 1),
    LastName = SUBSTR(LastName,CHARINDEX(' ',LastName) + 1, LEN(LastName))
WHERE MI IS NULL
    AND CHARINDEX(' ',LastName) > 0
```

You may have a few false positives but that should get the vast majority of cases.

I would STRONGLY recommend creating a transaction, doing the updates, doing a `SELECT` to see the results and rolling back the transaction since the update is not reversible.